# Laptop sometimes boots with an black screen

Tags: windows, boot, drivers, graphics-card, windows-11

So the problem i identified is my AMD Ryzen 7 6800H with integrated radeon graphics i think the BIOS or something uses the integrated graphics to boot thats why i dont see any boot information and also the time it happens cannot enter the BIOS. The Laptop still boots into windows and can be seen thorugh hdmi and an external monitor the Error code from the Amd Ryzen is 43:

```
Beim Start des Geräts PCI\VEN_1002&DEV_1681&SUBSYS_1CB21043&REV_C8\4&31f4ec98&0&0041 ist ein Problem aufgetreten.

Treibername: oem123.inf
Klassen-GUID: {4d36e968-e325-11ce-bfc1-08002be10318}
Dienst: amdwddmg
Untere Filter: 
Obere Filter: 
Problem: 0x0
Problemstatus: 0xC00000E5
```

I'm sorry its on German i can try translating it:

```
On start of device PCI\VEN_1002&DEV_1681&SUBSYS_1CB21043&REV_C8\4&31f4ec98&0&0041 an error occurred.
Drivername: oem123.inf
Class-GUID: {4d36e968-e325-11ce-bfc1-08002be10318}
Service: amdwddmg
Lower filters: 
Upper filter: 
Problem: 0x0
Problem status: 0xC00000E5
```

The laptop is the "ROG Strix G513RW"

If you need Information please ask.

Comment: This specific error goes back to at least [July 2021](https://community.amd.com/t5/drivers-software/amd-software-detected-that-the-display-driver-has-failed-to-load/td-p/479596) - error `0xC00000E5` indicates an application didn't start correctly for some arbitrary reason. Integrated graphics should always display, as they're the default graphics, whereas Discrete graphics are secondary/optional - have you tried disconnecting the external monitors before boot? Have you tried reinstalling the graphics driver from Asus' support site? Did you install a graphics driver other than that one?

Comment: _Cont'd..._ Booting with a black screen is likely the result of having an external monitor connected, as that's fairly common on laptops with integrated and discrete graphics.

Comment: @JW0914 Connecting an external Monitor was the temporary solution to the problem not the trigger. Yes i've tried installing the drivers multiple times didn't change anything.

Comment: Have you tried updating the BIOS version?